# BottomSheetDialogFragment неправильно отображает цвета

Tags: android

Собственно использую `BottomSheetDialogFragment` и заметил что неправильно отображаются цвета которые заданы через аттрибуты `android:textColor="?attr/colorAccent`". Выводятся какие то свои совсем непонятно откуда взятые...

Пробовал установить стиль , унаследоваться от `@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.BottomSheetDialog` заодно и углы закруглил , но не догоняю в чем дело.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.BaseBottomSheetDialog);
}


<!-- set the rounded drawable as background to your bottom sheet -->
<style name="BaseBottomSheetDialog" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/BottomSheet</item>

</style>

<style name="BottomSheet" parent="@style/Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_bottom_sheet_dialog_fragment</item>
</style>
```

Само приложение использует

```
<style name="Default_theme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Вопрос куда копнуть? Спасибо.

Comment: у вас проблема с цветами только bottomsheet или всех элементов?

Comment: Только конкретно в лайауте bottomSheetDialogFragment

Answer (score 1):

Собственно решил вопрос переопределением стиля и установкой его принудительно. Не знаю насколько это правильно, но работает так как нужно.

```
<style name="BaseBottomSheetDialog" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="BaseBottomSheetDialog.Dark" parent="@style/BaseBottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryDark_night</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark_night</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent_night</item>
</style>


 @Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(nightModeCheck()){
        setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.BaseBottomSheetDialog_Dark);
    }else {
        setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.BaseBottomSheetDialog);
    }
}
```